# Ember Data Many to Many shared items

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a user table, and an item table, each user owns some items.

so user 1 might own items with ids [1, 2, 3]
and user 2 owns items with ids [2, 3, 9, 24]

How would I set up this relationship based on ember data? Should I embed item ids in users? should I make a new table to describe who owns what? and how do I define and access a user's items in ember? If it depends on the database being SQL vs noSQL, give an example for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases have nothing to do with it.  It's completely dependent on your service endpoint (and not even that important since you can transform the data to adhere to Ember Data's expectations).

An example based on your stated structure would look something like this:

#### Model Definition

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),  // some random field
  items: DS.hasMany('item')
});


App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr()  // some random field
});
```

#### JSON response

```
{
users:[
  {
    id: 1,
    name:'Billy Bob',
    items:[1,2]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name:'Billy Joel',
    items:[1,3]
  }
],
items:[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "red"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "green"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "blue"
  }
 ]
}
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/822/edit

If you were to change the items to be asynchronous this would change slightly, but you can read up on that.

If you actually care about the items being able to traverse to the users you would follow the same pattern adding a `hasMany` on the items

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr(),  // some random field
  items: DS.hasMany('item')
});


App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  users: DS.hasMany('user'),
  name: DS.attr()  // some random field
});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jofodebe/1/edit